# Django admin - How do I display a list of Model X on Model Y 'add / change' page without a relationship?

Tags: django, django-admin

So I've got 2 models, BlogPost and BlogImage - the images are in the admin for ease of uploading without FTP, and for related metadata (title, etc.) However, I don't want any db link between BlogPosts and BlogImages - they'll be entered as HTML  tags in the body - but I would like something to reference while adding a new BlogPost.

Is there a way to display a list of BlogImage objects on the add BlogPost form? I've tried messing with overriding the change_list.html template for BlogPost, but I'm unsure how to provide additional data to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`extra_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        my_context = {
            'foo': 'bar',
        }
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            extra_context=my_context)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need. I tried the example, but I'm probably being stupid - how would I access the additional data provided in my_context from within the template? I tried {{ foo }}.

Comment: @dan-klasson: that's a bad way to add context. Generally, you want to do something like `extra_context = extra_context or {}` and then add additional keys to it as you see fit before passing it back into `super`. The way you've done it, any existing `extra_context` is overwritten, which amounts to a very confusing bug if that method is ever overridden in a subclass.

Comment: Do I need to do something special to have access to `extra_context` from within the template?

Comment: @Chris: That is from the documentation (that I also link to). I just copied it from there. But you're right, it is not a very good way of doing it.

Comment: @Tom: {{ foo }} should work. Are you overriding the template properly?

Comment: I'm just getting blank output when trying that for some reason, even with a test hardcoded value returned in the dictionary. I've overridden the change_form.html template which is overriding correctly, but doesn't appear to see the extra_context data.

Comment: @dan-klasson: Haha. Well, Django docs really dropped the ball there ;). Think I'll report that.